# Squares in squares with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to recreate the following layout with flexbox:
[image]

I am almost there layout wise, but I am getting some weird flex-wrap behaviour like this:

[image]

My css is as follows:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    .square-container {
      width: calc(33% - 1.333px);
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;

    &:before {
      content:'';
      float:left;
      padding-top:100%;
      }

      .small-square {
          width: calc(50% - 2px);
          height: calc(50% - 2px);
          background: red;
          flex-shrink: 0;
      }     
    }
}
```

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-square"></div>
</div>
```

I feel that I am missing some important flexbox property here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it quite easily:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 210px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 650px;
}

.small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.large {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Fully responsive with current html:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.parent:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 33.3333%;
}

.square-container {
  width: calc(33.33333% - 5px);
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.small-square {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  background: red;
}

.large-square {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33.33333%;
  background: red;
  order: 2;
}

.square-container:first-child {
  order: 1;
}

.square-container:nth-child(2n) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is an elegant solution.

Comment: This solution works great for a fixed size, but it does not seem to work if it needs to be responsive, i.e. the squares always need to occupy a space relative to the size of their parent, hence the percentages and the &:before.

Comment: how do you set the height of parent?

Comment: adding a pseudo element with padding-top that is equal to the width of the element.

Comment: I solved it like this without setting an explicit height for the parent - do you see any pitfalls? http://codepen.io/Jacobdo/pen/oZvBeO

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be the final solution for the problem, could you please edit your answer so I can approve it? Thanks.

Comment: I have found a better solution - with your current html - see above edit

Answer (score 1):

No changes to the HTML:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.square-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.small-square {
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.large-square {
  flex: 1;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.square-container:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
    <div class="small-square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-square"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1uLjyuy/2/)

Comment: This is a good solution assuming that the width is fixed, however, in my case, I need to to be responsive hence the use of percentage.

Comment: The width of `.parent` is not fixed, as you can see. The width of the three container's is `flex: 1`, meaning they'll equally distribute the width of the parent, whatever it may be. The width of the `small-square`s are percentages.

Comment: Sorry meant to say height, the inner squares are the ones defining height, so you either have to have margin around or increase the margin between the squares to compensate which is not the desired behaviour, please see the accepted answer. I realise that I should have posted a bit more detailed explanation.